# Photo Competition: July - Close up

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

Rules that are always applicable are as follows:

1. One photo per answer, and no more than 5 answers per user per contest.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself/person with you.
3. All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.
4. Refrain from posting sensitive/debatable content
5. Only upvotes count towards winning.

---

Rules for July are as follows:

1. **Close up - Macro photography, showing small things large.**
2. The contest will last the whole month of July and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself.
3. There is no constraint on when the photo must have been taken.

---

Suggest a theme for the next contest.

1. Leave a **single** comment below in the format
     THEME - ONE SENTENCE DESCRIPTION
2. Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next month.

Good luck!

Comment: Theme: **Activity** - people participating in the Great Outdoors

Comment: CharlieBrumbaugh please also consider suggestions mentioned in earlier competitions.

Comment: Hi Charlie! I just noticed a rule about voting, which I didn't see in previous contests (unless I missed it). It's #5, "Only upvotes count towards winning." What exactly does that mean? How is that different from previous contests? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: Hornet]

A hornet ready for take-off. Picture taken on a camp ground at the shores of Lake Ossiach, Austria, in 2010.

There was a whole nest in this tree, and while I was not fully comfortable taking that photo, fortunately the hornets didn't seem to care for my presence.

Answer (score 8):

Butterfly on a group of small flowers. Shot at the San Diego Safari Park during Butterfly Jungle exhibition in 2017(?).

[image: Butterfly on a group of small flowers]

Answer (score 5):

What was left of a small flower, likely after a few months or even a winter.

[image: remains after a flower went to seed.]

Photo taken in Heemskerk, the Netherlands, 31 August 2013, cropped out of a bigger picture to make it upload size.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Lifelines of lifelines if we can call it so. Macro of a leaf against the sunlight.
Date: About January 2019.
Place: India.

Answer (score 4):

A lovely little flower I spotted yesterday morning on the coast just south of Puerto Duquesa, Spain.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This is a picture of burnt soil people use to make bricks. Clicked on macro mode deliberately against the light.
Date: About March 2017.
Place: India.

Answer (score 3):

Picture taken in December of 2018 in Doi Luang National Park, Thailand. This spider make a mean, multi-level web and I actually overlooked it and got my head stuck in its golden web.

[image]

Per Jan's request, I'll add some size indication, but it's mostly guessing. I think the spider in its entirety would be the size of a large human fist.

Comment: Wow, it's gorgeous! You got your head in that web? I would have loved that (I understand not everyone feels that way)! Do you know the species? It would be fun to learn more about it, especially since I strongly doubt we have them in the United States!

Comment: @Sue by no means sure but I think it's a [*Nephila pilipes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephila_pilipes). It was actually on a trail with a lot of waterfalls, I wanted to take a picture a little bit off-trail and got my head in its web because I looked down to take safe steps. ;p

Comment: This, and other pics that were posted a few days later than the others, have not attracted enough votes.

Answer (score 3):

A dragonfly staying put on the tip of the branch, even if my camera gets near to it. Did not do focus stacking 'cause I'm not with my tripod.

Location: Kee's Farm, Malaysia.
Date: 26 June 2017.

[image: Dragonfly]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

My first ever click with a macro lens. Its flower, I don't know the name of, usually found in monsoon.
Date: About August 2017.
Place: India.

Answer (score 2):

[image: white flowers]

Flowers growing on the side of the river Thames, near Henley.
Photo taken 13 July 2019.
Photo cropped and reduced in size to get it uploaded.

The flower might be a [Meadow Sweet.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filipendula_ulmaria)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Some sort of unknown berries today, Colorado.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is an American robin fledgling. I thought it had left the nest too soon, but its dad chased away cowbirds and other prey, and its mom fed it. That's their job during the delicate and vulnerable period after fledging.

I took the picture from inside, through a window, so as not to disturb the parents. It was in Central Massachusetts, USA, on June 4, 2019.