# Photo Competition: August - Activity

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

Rules that are always applicable are as follows:

1. One photo per answer, and no more than 5 answers per user per contest.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself/person with you.
3. All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.
4. Refrain from posting sensitive/debatable content
5. Only upvotes count towards winning.

---

Rules for August are as follows:

1. **Activity - people participating in the Great Outdoors**
2. The contest will last the whole month of August and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself.
3. There is no constraint on when the photo must have been taken.

---

Suggest a theme for the next contest.

1. Leave a **single** comment below in the format
     THEME - ONE SENTENCE DESCRIPTION
2. Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next month.

Good luck!

Comment: Water, with or without people.  Water can be liquid (fresh or salt) or frozen.

Comment: Hi Charlie! Would you please explain what you mean by "Only upvotes count towards winning?" I just noticed it here and in the [July](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1513/) competition. How is it different from previous contests? Is it different from the way all voting is tabulated in the SE System? Thanks?

Comment: I raised this point in June; what turned out eventually to be the winning photo (the juvenile reindeer) was for some time tied for first place with another excellent photo.  However the juvenile reindeer had one downvote, and it was a gorgeous photo well within the rules.  Downvotes don't make sense in the photo contest because one cannot disagree with a valid photo (one that follows the rules) or find it "not useful."   If one thinks a photo is technically poor, a downvote might make sense, but it would be simpler and more sporting just to not upvote it.  @Charlie Brumbaugh -- what think you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## One large step for a man

This is my friend Tom making the step between the Adam and Eve rocks that are the highest points at [the summit of Tryfan](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/29580544#map=15/53.1118/-3.9976&layers=C) in north Wales; taken on Monday 2nd April 2007.

[image: Tom gains the Freedom of Tryfan]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Ski touring group]

A ski touring group ascending a mountain near Dalvík on Iceland in April 2018.

While I never got to enjoy a blue sky in the week I was there, skiing with a view of the sea was still a fantastic experience.

Answer (score 7):

Ok so not done one of these before but here's one :)

[image]

Peaceful Sunday morning kayaking on the local arm of the Grand Union canal in Bucks, UK. (Those are my feet!) - Aug 4, 2018

Answer (score 7):

[image]

One of my friends dangling off of El Capitan this summer

Comment: Date? (This summer is not very precise.)

Answer (score 6):

## Into the unknown

[image: Gwen maypoling Canada Cavern]
In October 2016, I was privileged to discover a previously unknown cave in Applecross in north-west Scotland, along with a visiting Canadian student.  We explored a couple of hundred metres of passage, but the upstream limit was a large chamber ten metres high, with a waterfall entering at the top where we couldn't get to.  We named this chamber Canada Cavern for its size and for Jessica's homeland, and were keen to find what lay above.

On Saturday 26th November that year (sadly after Jessica had left Scotland), four of us returned, equipped to explore its upper reaches.  Gwenllian, being the smallest and lightest, was volunteered to be the first to ascend, and to secure the ladder for the others.

On this day, we were able to reach right up to the ceiling of the chamber, about ten metres above its floor, and see across to where a waterfall enters.  It was another three months or so before we were able to engineer a route to the to the top of the waterfall and explore a further 100m of passage (later extended to over 200m through a choke and a long wet crawl).

If you're interested in the whole story of this discovery, you can read the full [exploration diary](http://coilleais.com/liars-sink/).

Answer (score 3):

[image: Man walking near one of the Chalkland white horses.]
Photo taken May 2016, [Cherhill White Horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherhill_White_Horse) with Ian leading the way.
Near Calne, Wiltshire UK.

Answer (score 3):

Devil's Kitchen/Llyn Idwal (Snowdonia, UK) walk with [AOAC](http://www.aoac.co.uk)
[image: Panorama - Devil's Kitchen/Llyn Idwal in winter]
28 December 2017

Answer (score 2):

Cycle touring [on South Uist](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=57.3005083&mlon=-7.3917500&zoom=14):

[image: Peter cycling on a sandy track]
Sunday 7th June 2009.